# How can I disable xterm.js's onkey event?

Tags: javascript, xtermjs

```
 _xterm.onKey((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      //.....
});
```

I want to disable onkey event of xterm when a button is pressed using one button. What should I do?

Comment: Question is - what do you want to achieve? Messing around with the event listeners yourself is not a good idea. Instead maybe just dispose/re-attach your `onData` handler on the button action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what are you looking for, but  you can try to use DOM's event methods in order to stop event propagation.

```js
xterm.onKey(e => {
    e.domEvent.stopPropagation()
    e.domEvent.preventDefault()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to disable xterm.js's onkey event

```js
const disposable =  _xterm.onKey((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      //.....
      // stop listening for consecutive events
      disposable.dispose();
});
```